# Kerning bug with Verdana in Firefox and Chrome at 15 pixels

Tags: fonts, truetype-fonts, typography

I asked this question originally on stackoverflow, but it was suggested that it would be more relevant here:

I noticed a kerning issue with Verdana at 15 pixels in Firefox and Chrome on Windows. In the word "before", there is extra space between the "o" and the "r".  I can't post a screenshot because I'm new on superuser, but you can see the screenshot on my original SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142603/kerning-bug-with-verdana-in-firefox-and-chrome-at-15-pixels

The text displays as expected in Internet Explorer.

Does that mean that there's a bug in the kerning table for the Open Type version of the font? Where would I even report a bug like that?

Comment: It is better to flag your SO post for moderator attention and get them to migrate it than to double post (for next time).